# PHP File Download Is Always Corrupt (50% of the time)

Tags: php, file, header, download, corrupt

I have a script which automatically downloads a file.
It works perfectly to download the file, but the problem is that 50% or more of the time, it downloads a corrupt file.

Usually deleting and downloading again works, but not always.

How can I make this download 100% of the time perfectly always, not corrupted?
The file size changes depending on the file being downloaded.

```
<?php

// Automatically Start File Download 
if (isset($_GET['filename'])):
    $filename = $_GET['filename'];
    $domain = "http://www.domain.com";
    $filepath = "/addons/downloads/websites/";

     //BUILD THE FILE INFORMATION
     $file = $domain . $filepath . $filename;
     // echo $filepath . $filename;
     // echo $file;

     //CREATE/OUTPUT THE HEADER
    if (file_exists("/home/unrealde/public_html/ebook/domain.com/".$filepath . $filename)):
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);

    else: 
        $errorMsg = "<b>Download Error: File $filename Doesnt Exist!</b> <br />Please Contact <a href='mailto:support@domain.com'>support@domain.com</a>";
    endif;

    echo $errorMsg;

else: 
    // don't download any file
endif;
?>
```

Comment: So...if it's always corrupt 50% of the time wouldn't it stand to reason that it's only corrupt half of the time?

Comment: How can something be 'always' and 50% of the time?

Comment: Just to be controversial :-) But seriously, I would like some help

Comment: Suggestion 1: sort out your indenting - it makes it really hard to read the code. Suggestion 2: use brace `{}` notation for your `if()`s rather than colon `:` notation; again, it'd be easier to read. (they're only suggestions, but it's easier to help when the code is easy to read :-))

Comment: Yes, please. This isn't python. You should only be using the colon notation in templates.

Comment: "50% of the time, it works every time."

Comment: Hmm? I like the colon notation better. It's easier for me to read. Also, what could be done to make the indenting easier to read? It looks very clean to me. P.S. I'm not a coder, I just write code when its necessary :)

Answer (score 2):

My hunch is that something in your program is outputting some data other than the file itself.

Have you looked at the corrupt file in a binary editor and compared it with a non-corrupt version? What you'll find is that either at the beginning or the end of the file, you have some unexpected data, and this is what is corrupting the file.

If you look that file this way, it may become very obvious what the problem is. For example, you may have the file, followed by an error message, in which case maybe your line `echo $errorMsg;` is the culprit.

Alternatively you may have some blank space. This could also be the same error message, or it could be that your PHP tags have blank lines above or below them, which are being printed.

My first suggestion would be, since the program is effectively finished when the file is output, to put an explicit `die;` function immediately after the `readfile();` line. This will categorically prevent any further spurious data being output once the file has been sent.

That won't help if the bad data is being sent before the `readfile();`, but it does rule out half the possible problems in one swoop.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I have added it and will test it out. If this isnt it, what can I do to "swoop" the front half of the file from adding data? Thanks!

Comment: Your `die;` advice worked for me, but only if I also placed `exit;` right after it (and removed ANYTHING else like spaces or `echo` calls afterwards.) THANKS!

Comment: @Basheer `die` and `exit` are synonyms in PHP; the both do exactly the same thing. If `did` didn't work, then `exit` won't be any different. So I think in your case, it's the removing all the spaces and `echo`s afterward that made the difference.

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed that. You are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just tar/gzip/zip the contents and provide a tar/gzip/zip file for download instead ?

Smaller file transfer increase chances of success over http transfer,
and more importantly, you can provide checksum for user to verify against

Comment: Verify the size of the file before downloading it and after. If they don't match, scrap and download again (i.e. checksum).

 It's impossible to guarantee "perfect always, uncorrupted" due to the nature of the internet (packets can be lost), so we program around that. 

The gzip solution is a great idea, assuming you have access to the files you're downloading (or the server that has those files, and can write a wrapper function that uses the Zip() library).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding error_reporting(0); at the beginning of the script. Just for fun. If you check php.net for readfile, others have reported that this helps.